# NSDate incorrect timezone interpretation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When I have a time-string with value "17:00:00 +0000", it is converted to 18:00:00 CET by the dateformatter. But I want to have 17:00:00 in the NSDate.

This is the code I use in a certain method to return a NSDate a object

```
NSString* time = @"17:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate* convertedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:time];
```

This is the part where I need the hour as an integer

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:time];
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
```

Hour will be 18 instead of 17.

Comment: The very first line looks wrong.  Really wrong.

Comment: I'm confused.  The above should read 17:00:00 UTC/GMT and set that value into the NSSDate.  It will not display "CET", because an NSDate doesn't contain a timezone.  When you later format it for display (with a different date formatter) that formatter may be set to display CET, but you didn't show us that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the code where you use your date and not where you convert string to date. You could try to set `calendar`'s time zone instead of `NSDateComponents`'s to get desired behaviour:

```
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
// and then do the rest
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:time];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
```

NSDate does not store any custom time zone (it stores all the data in the same "base" time zone), you can display NSDate instance converted to specified time zone, but can't set any time zone for any NSDate instance. So, time zones jumps in only when you display it to the user. Also, the rule of thumb says: always store/transmit data in UTC.

```
NSDate *date = ...
date.timeZone = ... // No such thing
// this is how you can see which time is represented by NSDate in a specific time zone
// note there's no such function as StringFromNSDateWithTimeZone
NSLog("TimeZone: %@", StringFromNSDateWithTimeZone(date, SOME_TIME_ZONE))
```

That means that you should check your NSDate display code but not your string to NSDate code (it seems to do what you'd expect).

Just to add more glue: `17:00:00 +0000 (GMT)` = `18:00:00 +0100 (CET)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I know that the dates are actually the same. In the debugger, NSDate always uses CET, which is the timezone of my computer.

I added the code where I want to have the hour of the NSDate.